# Data is duplicating using onSnapshot

Tags: jquery, firebase, bootstrap-4, google-cloud-firestore, bootstrap-modal

I am adding data to Cloud firestore using a bootstrap modal
I want a table to update the data when the modal is closed

**HTML for modal buttons**

```
<div class="modal-footer">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="submitStudent" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$( document ).ready(function(){

    //call the firebase.app namespace and store it to the the constant app
    const app = firebase.app();
    //log detail to console. 
    // not required but does allo the testing to see if the app is working
    console.log(app);
    //load the firebase db into the constant DB
    const db = firebase.firestore();


//JQUERY FOR GETTING A STUDENT DETAILS AND OUTPUTTING TO TABLE:


        db.collection("students").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {

        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            let student = doc.data();
            // pull the student data into the table, the escape characters between each set of data denote a new unit
            // currently this is handed pulled from the DB, however it would be better to use a for loop

            $('#overallDashboard > tbody:last-child').append(

                    '<tr> \
                        <th scope="row">'+doc.id+'</th> \
                         <td>'+student.first_name+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.last_name+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT1.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT1.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT1.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT2.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT2.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT2.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT3.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT3.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT3.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT6.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT6.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT6.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT8.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT8.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT8.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT9.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT9.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT9.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT12.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT12.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT12.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT13.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT13.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT13.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT15.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT15.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT15.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT17.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT17.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT17.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT21.CG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT21.PG+'</td> \
                         <td>'+student.UnitGrades.IT21.TG+'</td> \
                         \
                         <td>Calc</td> \
                         <td>Calc</td> \
                         <td>Calc</td> \
                     </tr>' 


                     );//close append



    }); //end for each loop
});//end onsnapshot



    // JQUERY CODE FOR ADDING A STUDENT

    // form for submitting function
    $("#submitStudent").click(function (event) {



        const db = firebase.firestore();
        console.log(db);

        //search document IDs in database
        let student = db.collection("students").doc($("#addStudentNumber").val());

            // add students to the DB
            student.get().then(function(doc) {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    console.log("Document already exists:", doc.data());


                } else {
                    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                    console.log("No such document!");

                    student.set({
                    "first_name": $("#addStudentFirstName").val(),
                    "last_name": $("#addStudentLastName").val(),
                    "DOB": $("#addStudentDOB").val(),
                    "completion_year": $("#addStudentCompletionYear").val(),
                    "student_number": $("#addStudentNumber").val(),
                    "student_email": $("#addStudentEmail").val(),
                    "UnitGrades":{ 
                        "IT1": { 
                            "id":"IT1",
                            "name":"Fundamentals of IT",
                            "type":"Exam",
                            "GLH":90,
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        }, 
                        "IT2": { 
                            "id":"IT2",
                            "name":"Global Information",
                            "type":"Exam",
                            "GLH":90,
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        },
                        "IT3": { 
                            "id":"IT3",
                            "name":"Cyber Security",
                            "type":"Exam",
                            "GLH":60,
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        },
                        "IT6": {
                            "id":"IT6",
                            "name":"Appilication Design",
                            "type":"CWK",
                            "GLH":60,
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        },
                        "IT8": { 
                            "id":"IT8",
                            "name":"Project Management",
                            "type":"CWK",
                            "GLH":60,
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        },
                        "IT9": { 
                            "id":"IT9",
                            "name":"Product Development",
                            "type":"CWK",
                            "GLH":60,
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        },
                        "IT12": { 
                            "id":"IT12",
                            "name":"Mobile Technology",
                            "type":"CWK",
                            "GLH":60,
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        },
                        "IT13": { 
                            "id":"IT13",
                            "name":"Social Media and Digital Marketing",
                            "type":"CWK",
                            "GLH":60,
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        },
                        "IT15": { 
                            "id":"IT15",
                            "name":"Games Design and Prototyping",
                            "type":"CWK",
                            "GLH":60,
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        },
                        "IT17": {
                            "id":"IT17",
                            "name":"Internet of Everything",
                            "type":"CWK",
                            "GLH":60, 
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        },
                        "IT21": { 
                            "id":"IT21",
                            "name":"Web Design and Prototyping",
                            "type":"CWK",
                            "GLH":60,
                            "CG": "F",
                            "PG": "F",
                            "TG": "F"
                        }
                    }
                    })
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log("Document successfully written!");

                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
                    });
                }

                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error getting document: ", error);
                });

                // outputData();

                db.collection("students").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

                });
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });

        }) //close submit form click function


//close document read function              
    });
```

I expect the table to show the new document that has been added

However all of the data in the database is appending to the bottom of the current data, I only want the new document to be shown in the page, preferably in order of the student forename.

**Update**

Using the response from Frank van Puffelen I have resolved this

I created a new html variable with a blank div inside
I then used .add to add the code for each iteration of the for loop as previously written.

I then used .html to call the variable html and update the page code.

```
db.collection("students").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {


                        let html = $("<div></div>");

                        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

                            let student = doc.data();



                            html = html.add($('<tr> \
                                        <th scope="row">'+doc.id+'</th> \
                                         <td>'+student.first_name+'</td> \
                                         <td>'+student.last_name+'</td> \
...
```

```
$('#overallDashboard > tbody:last-child').html(html);
```

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as the amount of code in your question is far beyond the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have this code that listens for data and changes in the database:

```
db.collection("students").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        let student = doc.data();

        $('#overallDashboard > tbody:last-child').append(
            ...
```

Keep in mind that `onSnapshot` gets called with all data in the collection. So when you first connect to Firestore, and whenever the data changes, you get all documents from `students` and **add** them to `#overallDashboard`. This means that the first time, you end up with all students. Say there are 3 students, you end up with a table with:

```
student 1
student 2
student 3
```

Now when there's a change, you **add** the complete data to the end of the table. So you end up with the original content **and** the changed content. Say that you're adding an additional student document, you end up with:

```
student 1 // first time onSnapshot got called
student 2
student 3
student 1 // second time onSnapshot got called
student 2
student 3
student 4
```

And when you then for example remove the first student, you end up with:

```
student 1 // first time onSnapshot got called
student 2
student 3
student 1 // second time onSnapshot got called
student 2
student 3
student 4
student 2 // third time onSnapshot got called
student 3
student 4
```

There are two solutions to the problem:

1. Clear out the table every time `onSnapshot` is called.
2. Determine the exact change that was made to the data, and **update** the HTML for that.

While the second approach is more efficient, it also is a bit more involved. So instead I'll show the simple approach below, which is to clear out the HTML in the table every time `onSnapshot` gets called:

```
db.collection("students").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        let student = doc.data();

        $('#overallDashboard > tbody:last-child').html(
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done this but now have an issue where only the last one is displayed. I think it is because I have ```let student = doc.data();``` within the forEach but not sure how to resolve this?

Comment: I have resolved this now, will edit the question above. Thanks for your help in putting me in the right direction